# Cloned project wont start when running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, debian

As the title says I cloned a project of mine on a virtual machine and I can't seem to start the RoR web server using "rails s". At first I thought I had a gem that was acting funny so I blocked it out in the Gemfile. However, when I did that another gem was not working. I'm currently at a loss of what to do so I was hoping someone could help me out. Thank you for reading and have a wonderful day!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  31: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

  30: from bin/rails:3:in `load'

  29: from /home/ncs/Karaz-Ankor/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'

  28: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'

  27: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'

  26: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'

  25: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'

  24: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'

  23: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'

  22: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'

  21: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'

  20: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'

  19: from /home/ncs/Karaz-Ankor/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
  18: from /home/ncs/Karaz-Ankor/bin/rails:9:in `require'

  17: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'

  16: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'

  15: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'

  14: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'

  13: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'

  12: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'

  11: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'

  10: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'

  9: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'

  8: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'

  7: from /home/ncs/Karaz-Ankor/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'

  6: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'

  5: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'

  4: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'

  3: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'

  2: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'

  1: from /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:84:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require': 
  There was an error while trying to load the gem 'uglifier'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)
  Gem Load Error is: Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/rails/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
  Backtrace for gem load error is:
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:58:in `autodetect'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/uglifier-4.1.19/lib/uglifier.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bundler-1.16.4/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
  /home/ncs/Karaz-Ankor/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `require'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:133:in `block in perform'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ncs/Karaz-Ankor/bin/rails:9:in `require'
  /home/ncs/Karaz-Ankor/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
  /home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
```

/home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in `require'
/home/ncs/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:70:in`require'
/home/ncs/Karaz-Ankor/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in`load'
bin/rails:3:in `'
Bundler Error Backtrace:

Comment: You need a JS runtime installed. Install Node.js first, and then try.. it will work

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a Javascript runtime installed.

If you are on Ubuntu or it's derivatives, you can install NodeJS runtime by running.

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

If you are using Debain

```
sudo aptitude install nodejs
```

To install nodejs on systems using yum, type the following in the terminal:

```
yum -y install nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the description posted, it shows that i the gem 'uglifier' was unble to install.

Uglifier is a JS wrapper and it needs a JS runtime running or JS interpreter.

Nodejs is not an essential, but a JS runtime or interpreter is.

And this is the role of NodeJS here.

If not NodeJS, you'll need another JS runtime/interpreter.

You should run following command to install NodeJS in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

or run this for OSX

```
brew install nodejs
```